# Standard normal random variable and their sum

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $X_1$ is a standard normal random variable. Define $X_2$ as
$X_2$ $=$ $-X_1$ if $|X_1|<1$ , and
                  $X_2$$=$$X_1$ , otherwise.

(a) Show that $X_2$ is also a standard normal random variable.
(b) Obtain the cumulative distribution function of $X_1 + X_2$ in terms of
the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random
variable.

Comment: So, you are saying that $X_2=X_1$, because in $X_2=X_1$ in both conditions. Are you sure your wording is correct?

Comment: Sorry sorry....edited that typo

Comment: Anything you tried? Same second question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361212/obtain-the-cumulative-distribution-function-of-x-1x-2

Comment: Thanks! @stubbornAtom

Comment: But how to prove part (a)?

Comment: Hint: note that the probability density function $f_{X_1}(x)$ is an even function, which implies $f_{X_1}(x)=f_{X_1}(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: First question is solved by finding the distribution function of $X_2$: \begin{align}
P(X_2\le x)&=P(-X_1\le x,|X_1|<1)+P(X_1\le x,|X_1|>1)
\\&=P(X_1\le x,|X_1|<1)+P(X_1\le x,|X_1|>1)
\\&=P(X_1\le x)
\end{align}  If you have solved the question, please answer and mark as accepted.